# Compare two files and replace

Tags: python

There are more than 1000 lines in file1, for example:

```
:)
still good
not
candy....wasn't even the good stuff.
how could i ever forget? #biggestdayoftheyear
not even think
will be
```

There are more than 1000 lines in file2, for example:

```
1,even,2
2,be,1
3,good,2
4,:),1
5,forget?,1
6,i,1
7,stuff.,1
8,#biggestdayoftheyear,1
9,think,1
10,will,1
11,how,1
12,not,2
13,the,1
14,still,1
15,ever,1
16,could,1
17,candy....wasn't,1
```

Codes:

```
file1 = 'C:/Users/Desktop/file1.txt'
file2 = 'C:/Users/Desktop/file2.txt'

with open(file1) as f1:
    for line1 in f1:
        sline1 = str(line1.strip().split(' '))
        print sline1

with open(file2) as f2:
    for line2 in f2:
        sline2 = line2.split(',')
        #print sline2[0], sline2[1]
        if sline2[1] in sline1:
            print sline1.replace(sline1, sline2[0])
```

From the codes the results show only:

```
2
6
10
```

Anything that I missed? Any suggestion?

I want to replace all words in file1 with number from 1st column from file2, after checking from the 2nd column whether they are the same words.

Expected result:

```
4
14 3
12
17 1 13 3 7
1 16 6 15 5 8
12 1 9
10 2
```

Comment: What's your question? Is something not working as you expect?

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mentioned.

Comment: Are the lines in the two files in any particular order? Must the first line in file 1 be compared to the first line in file 2 or must you loop through all the lines in file 2 for each line in file 1? If you do find a match, do you need to break out or do you continue searching for more matches?

Comment: @sabbahillel They not in order. They can change.

Comment: I think you should make some structures(classes) and then store both file data in them, and then search through structure, like dictionary.. or go word by word and search in second file!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to build an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) from file2.

```
inverted_index = {}
with open(file2) as f2:
   for line in f2:
       key, value, _ = line.split(',')
       inverted_index[value] = key
```

Then, use that inverted index to check while you loop through file1:

```
with open(file1) as f1:
    for line in f1:
        print ' '.join([inverted_index.get(word, word) for word in line.strip().split(' ')])
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you loop through file 1 and set sline1 explicitly. After you exit the loop, you loop through file 2 for the compare. As a result, you will only be processing the last value of sline1 (since you exited that loop). Once you build the dictionary inverted index as shown by Menno, you can then set up the replacement process.